# how do I select the first li of the second list?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

thi is the CSS class that I'm using:

```
.list {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: inherit !important;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.list li {
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: flex;
    line-height: 1.4;
    padding-left: 0;
    border-bottom: #454b52 1px solid;
}
```

HTML structure for the view:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

I want to target the first li of the secont list  to have padding: 0px 0px 10px for the mobile and tablet view.
I tried this selector but it doesn't work:

```
.list:nth-of-type(2) li:first-child{
    padding: 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do select **nth-*** of an **id,class...etc** yet in css, you can only do that by using as a selector the tag name `<ul>` for an example

You can do it like this:

```
ul:nth-of-type(2) li:first-of-type{
    /* your css properties here for the li */
}
```

## Javascript

you can do it using javascript like that:

```
elements = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
if (elements[1]) {
    // get first **li** 
    li = elements[1].firstElementChild;
    // try to change background color like this
    li.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the first `li` of the second `ul`, you need to use `:nth-child` css selector. You can find more information here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp.

So this is an example :

```css
.list {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: inherit !important;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.list li {
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: flex;
    line-height: 1.4;
    padding-left: 0;
    border-bottom: #454b52 1px solid;
}

ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1){
    border-bottom: red 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi your code is working fine. To understand that you pick the right element by .list:nth-of-type(2) li:first-child I used number in the li and use red color. Please check the below code:

```
<html>
<style>
.list {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: inherit !important;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.list li {
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: flex;
    line-height: 1.4;
    padding-left: 0;
    border-bottom: #454b52 1px solid;
}
.list:nth-of-type(2) li:first-child{
    padding: 0px 0px 10px;
    color: red;
}

</style>
<body>
    <ul class="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
</body>

</html>
```